# Why is possible to pass a function pointers as template parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Let us consider the excerpt:

```
void myFunc(int a, int b) {}

template<void(*function_pointer)(int, int)> 
class TakeFunctionPointer {
public:
  TakeFunctionPointer() {
    function_pointer(5, 6);
  }
};

int main() {
  TakeFunctionPointer<myFunc> tfp{};
}
```

This code is compiled finely and it works out, but I am concerned why does compiler allow to place function pointers into template parameters, because as I know templates in C++ are part of static polymorphism and it's expected that at first the compiler instantiates all template classes and then run them. So, it means that the compiler is able to take an address of function with the given signature and it places the address in fact. That allows the class to invoke the convenient function.
How come?

Comment: Why shouldn't this be possible?

Comment: If it is not weird enough, you can also have pointers to global variables as template parameters.

Comment: @Justin Rather I meant that I am interested on which step does the compiler have information about object's address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `class` type template arguments and value type arguments. When you have a template in which the actual type is already given, e.g.

```
template<std::size_t N> /* class or function... */
```

you are dealing with a value parameter. This is also true for specific pointers to functions, e.g.

```
template<void(*function_pointer)(int, int)> /* ... */
```

You instantiate this template with a particular function reference that matches the signature, and in the definition of the template, you can use this value.

Note that using function pointers like this, i.e. at compile time, is feasible because functions and their signatures must be known at compile time anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does compiler allow to place function pointers into template parameters?

Because the standard says that it is allowed.

> So, it means that the compiler is able to take an address of function with the given signature and it places the address in fact.

Correct.

Comment: Very short and concise answer! :)